# Protecting API keys in a published Google app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

We have a complex Google spreadsheet with supporting Google App Script code. We are in the process of verifying the app with Google. Once the app is verified and published what is the best way to protect the API key? Also, once it's published what is the best way to protect the code?

Comment: Are you publishing the Apps Script project as a Sheets "editor" add-on?  If not, that's what you need to do.  The functions in your server code should all end with an underbar to make them private.

Comment: What type of app is the one that you are publishing? Also, which API key are you trying to "protect"?

Comment: Our goal is to allow customers to use a copy of the sheet without having to go thru the google authorization. We have started the process of verifying the app with google and we have read that there is an API key that is assigned to a published app and warnings about protecting the API to avoid unauthorized use.  Our application is an accounting spreadsheet for small businesses. The sheet has various scripts attached. The primary function of the scripts is to help the user enter data, categorize, and generate reports within the spreadsheet.

Comment: In addition, there is a function that adds folders to organize the data and an email function that sends invoices to the customer. Based on this description do you still think an add-on approach is necessary vs just publishing the app?  Also, what is the purpose of the API key that is assigned?

Comment: And are you publishing the app as an add-on?